# neo4j using transactionListener causes read/write error

Tags: plugins, neo4j, listener

I'm trying to use `TransactionEventListener` in neo4j. There don't seem to be any lifecycle hooks for plugins, so I figure the only way to do it is to have a plugin procedure do it. However, trying to do that gives me this error:

```
Neo4jError: Writing in read access mode not allowed. Attempted write to internal graph 1 (system)
```

The plugin uses write mode, even if I'm not actually writing anything to the database; I'm just registering that `TransactionEventListener`, although that could indeed lead to writes later on. Still, I've got Write mode.

Here's my procedure:

```
@Procedure(name = "setTransactionListener", mode = Mode.WRITE)
public Stream<BuiltInProcedures.NodeResult> setTaxonomy(
        @Name("taxonomy") Map<String, Map<String, Object>[]> taxonomy
) {
    var managementService = new DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder(Path.of(".")).build();
    var listener = new ValidationTransactionListener(taxonomy);
    managementService.registerTransactionEventListener(db.databaseName(), listener);
    return null;
}
```

Best guess is that I'm not supposed to register a transaction listener this way. But if not this way, then how? There don't seem to be any lifecycle hooks that get called when the database starts, so how can I possibly register an transactionEventListener?

Or is there a way I can give myself permission to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you actually want to do?

It doesn't work like that, you need to register the listener in the database lifecycle within a KernelExtensionFactory?

See here for an example:

https://github.com/neo4j/apoc/blob/dev/common/src/main/java/apoc/ApocExtensionFactory.java#L53

Comment: I should probably post my own answer. I've got it working with a variation of that ExtensionFactory. Although the read/write error was caused by an error I made in a completely different location, so maybe it could work. But the ExtensionFactory gives me lifecycle hooks that the my previous approach doesn't.